# A rigorous treatment of the hyperreal numbers and nonstandard analysis.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, nonstandard-analysis

I tried finding a decent book to study nonstandard analysis from and found Goldblatt's *Lectures on the Hyperreals*. However, I was very disappointed to find out that the text is not rigorous at all --- Goldblatt doesn't even prove the transfer principle. Are there any completely rigorous treatments of the hyperreals?

Ideally, I would like them to cover the same content that Goldblatt's book does: construction, nonstandard analysis and miscellaneous applications. However, I'd be more than satisfied with just construction and nonstandard analysis. I would also like the book to be more-or-less self-contained in this regard. That is, if the book simply states the transfer principle is a consequence of some stronger model-theoretic theorem, I don't gain anything from that. Of course, some knowledge of analysis, algebra and logic must be assumed, and  I'm fine with all of those on a basic level.

To clarify, I am also not interested in axiomatic approaches to these structures. So, for example, a construction of the hyperreals would be much preferred over an axiomatic introduction.

Comment: "Of course, some knowledge of analysis, algebra and logic must be assumed, and I'm fine with all of those on a basic level." Are you already familiar with compactness? That's really the key ingredient for the hyperreals, and it's at the upper end of basic first-order logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am familiar with compactness.

Comment: As I look back at it, it seems Goldblatt's treatment is more telegraphic than I recalled.

Comment: Given that you're familiar with compactness, what proof have you seen? (The construction of a hyperreal field can be tailored to your favorite proof of compactness.) Or you can just go from compactness as an assumed principle: section 2.1 of [Goldbring's notes](https://www.math.uci.edu/~isaac/NSA%20notes.pdf) - which I learned from fwiw - gives the existence of a hyperreal field as a corollary of compactness, so if you're happy with compactness that approach should work regardless (note that Goldbring also sketches the ultraproduct-based construction in 2.2 but gives Los as an exercise there).

Comment: I didn't know that. I've actually already seen a construction of the hyperreals which I like in a paper of Isaac Davis: https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Davis.pdf

Sorry, clearly I'm too stupid to hyperlink properly in a comment. But I wouldn't mind seeing really any construction, as long as it wasn't handwavey. The one I've linked to seems intuitive enough, though.

Comment: At a glance, section 4.3 in Davis' write-up proves Los' theorem. But if you're already familiar with compactness, look at section 2.1 of Goldbring's notes linked above for the "no-unnecessary-details" version (= how to show that a hyperreal field exists using only the compactness theorem, without any assumption about which proof is used).

Comment: Since *proving every result used* is not at all related to *being rigorous*, it's really very hard to take a claim such as "Goldblatt's textbook non-rigorous at all" seriously. Especially when it all hinges on Goldblatt not proving Łoś's Theorem, a perfectly standard result whose proof can be found in any model theory textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original 1966 classic text is:

*Robinson, Abraham*, Non-standard analysis, Princeton, NJ: Princeton Univ. Press. xix, 293 p. (1996). [ZBL0843.26012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0843.26012).

This is a reprint of the 1974 second edition.

Answer (score 1):

*Nonstandard Analysis: Theory and Applications* (1997) edited by Arkeryd, Cutland, and Henson.

Covers "simple" nonstandard analysis (e.g. nonstandard extensions of a "simple" set), then "higher-order" nonstandard exstensions culminating in extensions of superstructures, and then goes on to cover real analysis, topology, probability, ODEs, etc.